# If $|x|<\epsilon, \forall \epsilon > 0$, then $x=0$

Tags: real-analysis, epsilon-delta

How do I start a proof like this? I am new to epsilon-delta proofs - I think this is a basic proof, I just want to see how someone would structure it properly.

Comment: Well, if $x \ne 0$, then $|x| > 0$, and choosing $\epsilon = ....$ leads to a contradiction.

Comment: How do I expand upon this?

Answer (score 7):

Suppose $x\neq 0$. Then $|x|>0$. Take $\epsilon = |x|/2$ and we have $|x|<\epsilon = |x|/2$, a contradiction.

Comment: Where does the $\frac{|x|}{2}$ come from?

Comment: I can take any $\epsilon>0$ I want, in particular I can take $\epsilon = |x|/2$. Of course, I could take any $\epsilon>0$ leading to a contradiction, for example, $\epsilon = |x|/42$.

Comment: I think $\epsilon = |x|$ is even easier. But the intuition, @sgerbhctim, is that if $x$ is not zero, then we can find an epsilon that is even smaller than $x$. So we need to just pick an $\epsilon$ that satisfies $0 < \epsilon \le |x|$.

Comment: Shouldn't that say |x| > epsilon, not less than?

Answer (score 1):

First of all let's say you are wrong, $x\ne 0$, now if $x\ne 0$ then $|x|>0$. Because you said for all $\epsilon$ any expression of $epsilon$ that is greater than $1$ should be valid. So let's try $\epsilon\equiv \frac{|x|}{n}, n\in\Bbb R^+, n>1$, because both $n$ and $|x|$ are positive $\epsilon$ is also positive. Now it is given that $|x|<\epsilon$ so $$|x|<\epsilon\implies |x|<\frac{|x|}{n}\implies 1<\frac{1}{n}$$because that $n>1$ we have contradiction. So $x=0$

Comment: You can also set $n$ to be any negative number and you will get the same contradiction

Comment: If $n\ge1$ there is a contradiction too.

Answer (score 0):

By hypothesis,
\begin{equation}
|x| < \frac{1}{n},~\forall n \in \mathbb{N} \tag{1}\label{eq}.
\end{equation}

Notice that \eqref{eq} holds if and only if 
\begin{equation}
-\frac{1}{n} < x < \frac{1}{n},~\forall n \in \mathbb{N}.
\end{equation}

By the [squeeze theorem for sequences](https://blogs.ubc.ca/infiniteseriesmodule/units/unit-1/infinite-sequences/squeeze-theorem-for-sequences/), we must have $x=0$.

Answer (score 0):

I like the answer that Hugo C Botós provided, nevertheless I can provide same solution but clearest.

In the language of mathematical logic, our proposition is,
$$\forall \epsilon > 0~(|x|<\epsilon \Longrightarrow x=0)$$

Proof.

Let $\epsilon \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $\epsilon > 0$. Suppose, to arrive at a contradiction, that $x\not=0$. Thus $|x|\geqslant 0$ and $x\not=0$, $|x|>0$. Given the class of the set of positive numbers, thus $|x|>0$ and $\frac{1}{2}>0$, $\frac{|x|}{2}>0$.

Since the quantifier is $\forall \epsilon >0$, in particular, it is for $\epsilon = \frac{|x|}{2}>0$. Clearly $\epsilon = \frac{|x|}{2}<|x|$ and, by hypothesis, $|x|<\epsilon$. Using the transitivity of the relation $<$, thus $\epsilon = \frac{|x|}{2}<|x|$ and $|x|<\epsilon$, $\epsilon < |x| < \epsilon$, which is a contradiction because $\epsilon \not< \epsilon$.

The contradiction comes from supposing that $x\not=0$. Therefore, $x=0$.

$\therefore \forall \epsilon > 0~(|x|<\epsilon \Longrightarrow x=0)$.

Comment: This answer is wrong.  The statement $\forall \epsilon>0(|x|<\epsilon \Rightarrow x = 0)$ is false.  But that is not the correct way to express the theorem under discussion.  The correct statement is $(\forall \epsilon > 0(|x| < \epsilon)) \Rightarrow x = 0$.  The "$\forall \epsilon > 0$" applies only to $|x| < \epsilon$, not to the entire implication.